# Google Timeline chart error

Tags: angular

i use angular 4 and google timeline chart it's give an error like **'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timeline' of undefined'** and my code like

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>          
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

**dasbordComponets.ts**

```
declare var google: any;

public initGraph() {
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['timeline']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.testGraph());
}

public testGraph () {
    var container = document.getElementById('graph');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
        [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
        [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

**dasbordComponets.html**

```
 <div id="graph" style="height: 180px;"></div>
```

Comment: no it's not similar question my error is ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timeline' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm working now with **Google timeline Angular** try by using this repository `npm i ng2-google-charts`  you just need install it and follow the following code:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Timeline chart</h1>
<google-chart [data]="timelineChartData"></google-chart>
```

**Component.ts**

```
public timelineChartData:any =  {
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    dataTable: [
      ['Name', 'From', 'To'],
      [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
    ]
 }
```

**Module.ts**

```
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        Ng2GoogleChartsModule,
        ...
    ],

...
```

Here a [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-timeline-chart) working.